# how to keep user contacts in bluestacks' whatsapp?

Tags: windows-7, bluestacks, whatsapp

I have been using BlueStacks in Windows 7 for quite a while. Mostly I use it because I have installed the whatsapp application on it. The problem that I have is from time to time when my Windows updates the BlueStacks stops working; it gets stuck with a black screen in the loading.

In some forums recommends to reverse the last windows update so BS will work, but no luck at all. The only solution that I found is to reinstall BS, but when I do that I lose all the information from my whatsapp.

I was wondering if there is a way to store my contacts from whatsapp in BS, is it store in some folder in my main drive? 
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like you mention Re installing bluestacks works, but you also media and contacts. The only workaround that I have found till now is to upload all your contacts to Google contacts>
then import it in your computer in .vcf file> drag and drop this file in bluestacks > using ES file explorer navigate to this file and click on this contact file. And all the contacts would be imported.

You may have to repeat this process every-time you re install bluestacks but this won't take more than a min.